# Finding all the values of $\sqrt[3]{7-4i}$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I'm reading about De Moivre's Formula and the Roots of Unity, and one of the exercises is to find all the different values of

$$
\sqrt[3]{7-4i}
$$

I know that you can find the $n$th root of 1 with $x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\dots+x+1=0$, but I don't know how to find the $n$th root of an arbitrary complex number. I tried sketching it geometrically on an Argand diagram by plotting some kind of triangle, but I'm not sure it was correct and didn't help find the roots anyway.

Is there a strategy for doing this (preferably in line with the content of De Moivre formula and roots of unity)?

Comment: Write down the formula, forget about the cube root for now. Rewrite $ 7- 4i$

Comment: @Nameless Rewrite it using which formula? The only formula I have is finding the roots of 1.

Comment: use that $$\sqrt[n]{z}=\sqrt[n]{r}=\left(\cos(\frac{\phi+2k\pi}{n})+i\sin(\frac{\phi+2k \pi}{n})\right)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Does $k$ represent the amount of revolutions around the real axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: We have $$\sqrt[3]{7-4i}=(7-4i)^{1/3}$$
$$r=\sqrt{7^2+(-4)^2}=\sqrt{65}$$ $$\tan \theta=\left|\frac{-4}{7}\right|=\frac{4}{7}$$ Since, the point $(7, -4)$ lies in the fourth quadrant hence we have   $$\sin \theta=\frac{\frac{4}{7}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^2}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{65}}$$ $$\cos \theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^2}}=\frac{7}{\sqrt{65}}$$ Now, we have $$(7-4i)^{1/3}=r^{1/3}(\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta))^{1/3}$$
$$=\sqrt[3]{65}\left(\cos \theta -i\sin \theta\right)^{1/3}$$ $$=\sqrt[3]{65}\left(\cos\frac{(2k\pi+\theta)}{3} -i\sin\frac{(2k\pi+\theta)}{3}\right)$$  Now, substitute $k=0, 1, 2$

Can you proceed further?

Comment: Shouldn't $\sin\theta=\frac{4}{\sqrt{65}}$ and $\cos\theta=\frac{7}{\sqrt{65}}$, since the opposite side is $4i$ and the adjacent $7$?

Comment: Kindly, check the point $(7, -4)$ lies in the fourth quadrant hence $\theta$ is negative & in fourth quadrant $sin \theta$ is negative & $\cos \theta$ is positive

Comment: I get that it's in the fourth quadrant, and only $\cos\theta$ can be positive. I don't understand why $65$ is the denominator rather than $\sqrt{65}$

Comment: Oh, sorry you are absolutely right. denominator must be $\sqrt{65}$

Comment: Okay, I understand. Is $\sqrt[3/2]{65}\left(\cos \frac{3\theta}{2} -i\sin\frac{ 3\theta}{2}\right)$ the final form, or do I have to link this with the values we attained for $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$?

Comment: you may link with the values obtained or solve otherwise keeping in view the point $(7, -4)$ is in fourth quadrant or amplitude $\theta$ is negative lying in fourth quadrant

Comment: Two final questions: 1) I'm not sure how to proceed to solve this, could you provide more help please? 2) In your first line, doesn't $\sqrt[3]{7-4i} = (7-4i)^{\frac{1}{3}}$?

Answer (score 0):

**$$ 7-4i=\sqrt{7^2+4^2} e^{i\theta}\\tan \theta =\frac{-4}{7} \rightarrow \theta \sim -29.7^0$$ now consider :$$a=7-4i=\\a=\sqrt{65} e^{i\theta}=\sqrt{65} e^{-29.7^0i}=\sqrt{65} e^{(-29.7^0+2k\pi )i}\\$$ and now 
$$\sqrt[3]{a}= a^{\frac{1}{3}}=(\sqrt{65} e^{(-29.7^0+2k\pi )i})^{\frac{1}{3}}\\(\sqrt{65})^{\frac{1}{3}} e^{\frac{(-29.7^0+2k\pi )}{3}i}$$** 
so put $$ n=0,1,2$ to have the roots

Comment: I would strongly suggest you not mix degree and radian measure. Better leave everything in radians.

Comment: What does $e^{i\theta}$ stand for? I've not come across this shorthand yet.

Comment: $$e^{i \theta} =cos \theta  + i sin \theta \\z=x+iy=|z|e^{i \theta}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} e^{i \theta}$$ this polar form

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt[3]{7-4i}=$$
$$\left|\sqrt[3]{7-4i}\right|e^{\arg\left(\sqrt[3]{7-4i}\right)i}=$$
$$\left|7-4i\right|^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{\arg\left(\sqrt[3]{7-4i}\right)i}=$$
$$\sqrt{\Re(7-4i)^2+\Im(7-4i)^2}^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{\arg\left(\sqrt[3]{7-4i}\right)i}=$$
$$\sqrt{7^2+4^2}^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{\arg\left(\sqrt[3]{7-4i}\right)i}=$$
$$\sqrt{65}^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{\arg\left(\sqrt[3]{7-4i}\right)i}=$$
$$65^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}}e^{\arg\left(\sqrt[3]{7-4i}\right)i}=$$
$$65^{\frac{1}{6}}e^{\arg\left(\sqrt[3]{7-4i}\right)i}=$$
$$\sqrt[6]{65}e^{\arg\left(\sqrt[3]{7-4i}\right)i}=$$
$$\sqrt[6]{65}e^{-\frac{1}{3}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)i}$$

Comment: Why does $\sqrt[3]{7-4i}=\left|\sqrt[3]{7-4i}\right|e^{\arg\left(\sqrt[3]{7-4i}\right)i}$? I haven't used the $e^{arg}$ syntax before.

Comment: It is a conversion from rectangular coordinates to polar. the absolute value is the radius and the argument is the angle.

Comment: @hohner it's the formula of Euler